# Adding an extra layer of row names in R tables for Quarto

Tags: r, formatting, kable, quarto

I am formatting a table in Quarto and I want to add an extra layer of headers to the left of my table. I can add an extra layer of column headers using the add_header_above() function in kable() but I can't figure out how to do the same for the rows.

```
df<-data.frame(x1=c(1,2,3,1), x2=c(2,4,6,2), x3=c(3,2,5,1), x4=c(2,3,4,4))
rownames(df)<-c("y1", "y2", "y3", "y4")
kable(df, booktabs=T) %>% kable_styling() %>% add_header_above(c(" "=1, "Group1"=2, "Group2"=2))%>%
  column_spec(column = 1,  bold=T, border_right = "1px solid lightgray")
```

Basically I want to an extra header on the left that looks the same as the one on top. The closest that I can figure out is:

```
df<-data.frame(x1=c(1,2,3,1), x2=c(2,4,6,2), x3=c(3,2,5,1), x4=c(2,3,4,4))
rownames(df)<-c("y1", "y2", "y3", "y4")
cbind(" "=rownames(df), df)
rownames(df)<-c("Group1", " ", "Group2", "  ")
kable(df, booktabs=T) %>% kable_styling() %>% add_header_above(c(" "=1, "Group1"=2, "Group2"=2))%>%
  column_spec(column=2, bold=T, border_right = "2px solid lightgray") %>%#
  column_spec(column = 1,  bold=T, border_right = "1px solid lightgray")
```

It's functional but I can't figure out how to turn text on the left so that's it's 90 degrees. Row_specs has the angle argument but I don't see anything similar for column_specs. The table doesn't have to be made using kable().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out another option using flextable so I figured I'd post it here.

```
df<-data.frame(x1=c(1,2,3,1), x2=c(2,4,6,2), x3=c(3,2,5,1), x4=c(2,3,4,4))
df<-cbind(" "=c("Group1", "  ", "Group2", "  "), "  "=c("y1", "y2", "y3", "y4"), df)
flextable(df)%>%
  align(align = "center", part="all") %>%
  add_header_row(., values=c("   ", "Group 1", "Group2"), colwidths=c(2, 2, 2)) %>%
  rotate(., j=1, rotation="btlr") %>% 
  merge_at(., j=1, i=1:2) %>% 
  merge_at(., j=1, i=3:4) %>%
  hline(., i=c(2,4)) %>%
  fix_border_issues(., part="all")%>%
  vline(., j=c(1,2,4))
```